# How to disable TabNine extension for only one language?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to disable TabNine extension for HTML files, is that possible?

Comment: I'd look for the answer or raise an issue [on their Github page](https://github.com/zxqfl/TabNine/issues).

Comment: look where? there's already an issue opened there that's why I asked here...

Comment: So I don't think that it is currently possible.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After some time I had the pleasure to discover how to do it! You need to use the `tabnine.disable_file_regex` attribute, so for example if you want to disable for md,html and css files do this:

```
  "tabnine.disable_file_regex": [
    "[.]md$",
    "[.]html$",
    "[.]css$",
  ]
```

You can do for any extension! Hope this help others

Comment: Just a small note:  this goes in your vscode user or workspace settings.

Answer (score 3):

My tabnine setting in VSCode doesn't appear to have a 'disable_file_regex' option but it does have a "tabnine.disabledLanguagesIds" option. I set mine to `"tabnine.disabledLanguagesIds": [   "txt", "html"]` . It works for me.